# Managing Longtable with Single-Row Contents Exceeding One Page's Length and Being Truncated

Tags: tables, longtable, thesis

I have a long table which I need to include in my thesis appendix.

However, I'm encountering an issue where, within certain rows, I have a list of genes that span over an entire page. Instead of these gene lists continuing onto a new page, they're being truncated. This problem persists across multiple rows in the table. How can I ensure that the table content flows seamlessly onto a new page instead of being cut off?

I'm currently employing the `longtable` package, but I'm open to using alternative packages if they offer a better solution.

(There are work arounds, but if someone finds a way to have the table automatically split across multiple pages, like it does in MS Word, then I will tick that answer)

Here is the first two rows of my table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{p{0.7in} >{\itshape}p{5in}}
    \caption{caption}
    \label{label}

    % Col names
    \hline
    \textbf{Group} & \textbf{Genes}
    \hline

    % contents of table:
Group 1 & ANKRD54, APC2, ARFGEF2, C3orf20, C6orf223, COQ9, DLEU1, DNLZ, DYRK3, ECI1, ERMARD, FAHD1, FBL, FBXO22, FBXO5, GATAD1, GPR143, GRAMD4, HCFC1, HEATR3, HSPA4L, HTR7P1, HYAL2, IRF5, KIF2C, LOC100996724, LOC102723324, LOC105376933, LOC105379437, LOC107984436, LOC107985246, LOC112268051, LOC729609, LPAR1, MAK16, MBNL1-AS1, MCM6, MFSD13B, MISP3, MPHOSPH10, MSANTD4, MYC, NHEJ1, NUP62, PIGM, PLA2G6, PNO1, PTTG2, RBM4B, SEMA7A, SLC52A2, SMAD7, SNORD36A, STT3A-AS1, TCERG1, THTPA, TIGD4, TIPIN, TMEM169, TNFAIP1, UGGT2, USP24, USP32P2, WDR77, ZDHHC4, ZNF142, ZNF320, ZNF584, ZNF815P\\

Group 2 & ABHD13, ABHD18, ABHD5, ABRACL, ABRAXAS1, ACBD3, ACSL4, ADD1, ADI1, AGO4, AHCTF1, AHCTF1P1, AIF1, AMFR, ANAPC13, ANKIB1, ANKRD42, ANP32B, ANXA11, ANXA3, AP3B1, AP3S1, APOL6, ARHGAP45, ARHGEF11, ARL3, ARL6IP4, ARPC4, ARPC5, ASH2L, ATAD1, ATF4, ATG4B, ATOX1, ATP5F1E, ATP5IF1, ATP5MC2, ATP5ME, ATP5MF, ATP5MG, ATP5MPL, ATP5PB, ATP7A, ATRX, BAG1, BBIP1, BICD2, BICRAL, BLOC1S2, BLZF1, BRCA1, BTBD10, BUD31, C11orf54, C19orf53, C2orf76, C4orf3, C4orf48, C5AR2, C6orf89, CAB39, CAB39L, CABP7, CALM1, CALM2, CALM3, CAMTA1, CARS2, CASC4, CASTOR2, CBFA2T3, CBFB, CBWD1, CBX1, CCDC13, CCDC146, CCDC170, CCDC71L, CCDC9, CD37, CD59, CDC40, CDK11A, CDKN2D, CEMIP2, CEP19, CEP57, CEP63, CFAP45, CFDP1, CHCHD7, CHD8, CHFR, CIAO1, CIAO2A, CINP, CIR1, CLEC12B, CLEC2B, CLMP, CLN8, CMTM2, CNBP, CNOT7, COMMD2, COMMD6, COP1, COPS5, COX14, COX17, COX5A, COX5B, COX6A1, COX6B1, COX8A, CPEB2, CPSF7, CREB5, CSNK1G3, CSTA, CTCF, CTDNEP1, CUL4B, CUX1, CXorf38, CYB561D2, CYB5B, CYB5R1, CYSLTR1, CYTOR, DAD1, DAPK1, DAPP1, DBI, DCAF7, DEF6, DEK, DENND10, DENND10P1, DIP2B, DNAJA2, DNAJB14, DNAJB6, DPH3, DPP8, DRC1, DTX3L, DUSP22, DYNLRB1, DYNLT1, EAF2, EEF1B2, EEPD1, EGLN1, EIF2S2, EIF4EBP1, EIF4EBP2, ELMOD2, ELOB, EMBP1, EMSY, ENY2, ERF, ESD, EVI2A, EVI2B, EXOSC3, FAM133B, FAM136A, FAM160B1, FAM200B, FAM204A, FAM49A, FAM76B, FAR1, FAS, FAU, FBXL3, FBXL4, FCGR1B, FIG4, FIS1, FLI1, FOCAD, FOSB, FOXJ2, FOXJ3, FRAT2, FUT4, GABARAP, GALM, GDAP2, GIMAP4, GLRX, GLRX3, GLYR1, GMFG, GNAQ, GNG5, GOLT1B, GPN3, GPR141, GPR27, GPS2, GPSM3, GRIPAP1, GRK3, GSN, GSR, GSTK1, GSTP1, H2AC6, H2AZ1, H2BC4, H3-3A, H4C8, HADHB, HLA-B, HLX, HMCES, HMGB1, HMGN2, HMGN4, HNRNPA1, HNRNPDL, HRH2, HSBP1, HSP90B2P, HSPB11, HSPD1, HTATIP2, IFI6, IFIT5, IFITM2, IGFLR1, IGSF6, IL17RA, INTS8, IRF1, ISCU, ITM2B, ITPR2, JPT1, KCTD12, KIAA1143, KIAA2013, KIDINS220, KIF2A, KPNA4, KPNB1, LAGE3, LAMTOR2, LAMTOR4, LAMTOR5, LARP7, LASP1, LEPROT, LEPROTL1, LIN7C, LINC00623, LINC00910, LINC01138, LINC01506, LINC02067, LINC02158, LIX1L, LLPH, LOC100506023, LOC100507507, LOC101928595, LOC102723373, LOC102723878, LOC105372421, LOC105372499, LOC105373098, LOC105373582, LOC105374102, LOC105374121, LOC105374985, LOC105375713, LOC105376244, LOC105376287, LOC105376512, LOC105376786, LOC105377067, LOC105378819, LOC107984747, LOC107986158, LOC107987225, LOC112268267, LOC643072, LPIN2, LSM3, LST1, LXN, LY96, LYPLA1, LYRM1, LYST, LYZ, MACROH2A1, MALSU1, MAN1A2, MAP2K4, MAPK1, MBD2, MCTS1, MED10, MED11, MED13L, MED25, METTL14, MICOS10, MIR142, MIR22HG, MMP25, MPC2, MRPL50, MRPL53, MRPS31, MRPS36, MS4A6A, MSRA, MTHFD2, MTMR1, MYLIP, NAA38, NACA4P, NAT9, NCF2, NDRG3, NDUFA1, NDUFA12, NDUFA2, NDUFA4, NDUFA5, NDUFA7, NDUFB1, NDUFB3, NDUFB6, NDUFV3, NEDD8, NEK7, NFRKB, NFYA, NLRC5, NMNAT1, NOP10, NOTCH1, NSD3, NSMCE1-DT, NTMT1, NUDT16, NUTF2, OARD1, OGFR, ORC4, ORMDL2, OSER1, OST4, OXR1, P2RY13, PABPC1, PAIP2, PARP14, PCMT1, PDCD4-AS1, PDPK1, PDPR, PELI2, PGLS, PGM2, PGM5, PHF21A, PHKB, PIGX, PIK3CD, PIN4, PLEKHA3, PLPBP, PNPT1, POLR2I, POLR2J, PPM1A, PPM1F, PPM1M, PPP2R5C, PQBP1, PRDX5, PRPF18, PRPF4B, PRR34-AS1, PRRG4, PSMA5, PSMA7, PSMB3, PSMB7, PSMB8, PSMD10, PSMD6, PSME1, PSME2, PSME4, PSTPIP1, PTBP2, PTENP1, PTOV1-AS2, PTPRN2, PXN, PYCARD, RAB33B, RAB5IF, RABAC1, RABGAP1, RABIF, RALBP1, RALY, RANBP3, RARA, RARS2, RASGRP2, RASSF3, RBM17, RBM26, RBP7, RCBTB2, RCOR1, RELCH, REM2, RFX1, RGS14, RHOT1, RNF114, RNF141, RNF145, RNF181, RNF20, RNF213, RNF38, RNF44, RNFT1, RNPEP, ROPN1L, RP2, RPA3, RPL13, RPL21, RPL23A, RPL24, RPL26, RPL27A, RPL29, RPL34, RPL35A, RPL36AL, RPL37, RPL38, RPL7A, RPL9, RPS11, RPS12, RPS15, RPS19, RPS19BP1, RPS24, RPS26, RPS27A, RPS3, RPS7, RPS9, RRP12, RSRP1, RTN4, RUFY2, S100A11, S100A12, S100A4, S100A6, S100A8, S100A9, S1PR4, SAP18, SAR1A, SBF2, SCAF8, SCARNA10, SCFD1, SCNM1, SDHB, SDHD, SEC11A, SEC22C, SEMA4A, SEMA4D, SENP5, SENP6, SERTAD3, SF3A1, SF3B5, SF3B6, SFPQ, SFSWAP, SGPL1, SH3GLB1, SIAH2, SLC25A5, SLC31A1, SLC35A1, SLC44A2, SLC45A4, SLC48A1, SLC8A1-AS1, SLCO3A1, SMARCA5, SMIM14, SMIM25, SMIM26, SMIM27, SMIM7, SNAPC5, SNF8, SNORA105A, SNORD141B, SNORD14D, SNORD14E, SNRK, SNRNP25, SNRNP27, SNRNP70, SNRPE, SNTB1, SNX2, SNX3, SP140, SP140L, SPCS1, SPIDR, SPTLC2, SREK1IP1, SRP14, SRSF9, SS18L2, ST3GAL6, STAG1, STAMBP, STAT2, STEAP4, STX3, STXBP5, SULT1B1, SUPT16H, SVBP, SWAP70, SYF2, TACC1, TAF10, TAF12, TARDBP, TBC1D1, TBCA, TBL1X, TFEB, TGFBR2, THAP1, THOC2, TIAL1, TIMM8B, TIPRL, TMA7, TMCO1, TMCO6, TMEM107, TMEM131L, TMEM144, TMEM14B, TMEM159, TMEM199, TMEM219, TMEM30A, TMEM50A, TMEM70, TMSB4X, TOPORS, TOR1AIP2, TPRG1L, TPST2, TRADD, TRAF3IP2-AS1, TRAPPC1, TRAPPC6B, TRDMT1, TRIOBP, TRMT10A, TRMT112, TSPAN2, TTC1, TTC17, TTC9C, TUBA1C, TUBGCP4, TUSC2, TXN, TXNDC17, TXNDC9, TXNIP, TXNL4B, TYROBP, U2AF1L5, UBA3, UBA52, UBC, UBE2D1, UBE2K, UBE2L3, UBE2R2, UBR3, UNC93B1, UPF2, UQCR10, UQCR11, UQCRC1, USP25, USP47, UTP6, VAMP3, VAMP4, VAMP5, VAPA, VNN2, VPS29, VPS36, VPS41, WBP4, WDR82, WDR83OS, WIPF1, WIPI1, XAF1, XPNPEP3, YIPF1, YPEL5, YY1, ZBTB18, ZBTB34, ZBTB8OS, ZCCHC9, ZDHHC17, ZFAS1, ZFP36L2, ZFP91, ZMAT2, ZMAT5, ZNF200, ZNF271P, ZNF284, ZNF516, ZNF641, ZNF700, ZNF770, ZNF776, ZNF90, ZNHIT1\\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: a table cell is an unbreakable box, so you want to use a list here not a table

Answer (score 2):

Table cells can not be broken across pages. You want a list here, not a table:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}\sloppy
\item [Group 1]ANKRD54, APC2, ARFGEF2, C3orf20, C6orf223, COQ9, DLEU1, DNLZ, DYRK3, ECI1, ERMARD, FAHD1, FBL, FBXO22, FBXO5, GATAD1, GPR143, GRAMD4, HCFC1, HEATR3, HSPA4L, HTR7P1, HYAL2, IRF5, KIF2C, LOC100996724, LOC102723324, LOC105376933, LOC105379437, LOC107984436, LOC107985246, LOC112268051, LOC729609, LPAR1, MAK16, MBNL1-AS1, MCM6, MFSD13B, MISP3, MPHOSPH10, MSANTD4, MYC, NHEJ1, NUP62, PIGM, PLA2G6, PNO1, PTTG2, RBM4B, SEMA7A, SLC52A2, SMAD7, SNORD36A, STT3A-AS1, TCERG1, THTPA, TIGD4, TIPIN, TMEM169, TNFAIP1, UGGT2, USP24, USP32P2, WDR77, ZDHHC4, ZNF142, ZNF320, ZNF584, ZNF815P

\item[Group 2]ABHD13, ABHD18, ABHD5, ABRACL, ABRAXAS1, ACBD3, ACSL4, ADD1, ADI1, AGO4, AHCTF1, AHCTF1P1, AIF1, AMFR, ANAPC13, ANKIB1, ANKRD42, ANP32B, ANXA11, ANXA3, AP3B1, AP3S1, APOL6, ARHGAP45, ARHGEF11, ARL3, ARL6IP4, ARPC4, ARPC5, ASH2L, ATAD1, ATF4, ATG4B, ATOX1, ATP5F1E, ATP5IF1, ATP5MC2, ATP5ME, ATP5MF, ATP5MG, ATP5MPL, ATP5PB, ATP7A, ATRX, BAG1, BBIP1, BICD2, BICRAL, BLOC1S2, BLZF1, BRCA1, BTBD10, BUD31, C11orf54, C19orf53, C2orf76, C4orf3, C4orf48, C5AR2, C6orf89, CAB39, CAB39L, CABP7, CALM1, CALM2, CALM3, CAMTA1, CARS2, CASC4, CASTOR2, CBFA2T3, CBFB, CBWD1, CBX1, CCDC13, CCDC146, CCDC170, CCDC71L, CCDC9, CD37, CD59, CDC40, CDK11A, CDKN2D, CEMIP2, CEP19, CEP57, CEP63, CFAP45, CFDP1, CHCHD7, CHD8, CHFR, CIAO1, CIAO2A, CINP, CIR1, CLEC12B, CLEC2B, CLMP, CLN8, CMTM2, CNBP, CNOT7, COMMD2, COMMD6, COP1, COPS5, COX14, COX17, COX5A, COX5B, COX6A1, COX6B1, COX8A, CPEB2, CPSF7, CREB5, CSNK1G3, CSTA, CTCF, CTDNEP1, CUL4B, CUX1, CXorf38, CYB561D2, CYB5B, CYB5R1, CYSLTR1, CYTOR, DAD1, DAPK1, DAPP1, DBI, DCAF7, DEF6, DEK, DENND10, DENND10P1, DIP2B, DNAJA2, DNAJB14, DNAJB6, DPH3, DPP8, DRC1, DTX3L, DUSP22, DYNLRB1, DYNLT1, EAF2, EEF1B2, EEPD1, EGLN1, EIF2S2, EIF4EBP1, EIF4EBP2, ELMOD2, ELOB, EMBP1, EMSY, ENY2, ERF, ESD, EVI2A, EVI2B, EXOSC3, FAM133B, FAM136A, FAM160B1, FAM200B, FAM204A, FAM49A, FAM76B, FAR1, FAS, FAU, FBXL3, FBXL4, FCGR1B, FIG4, FIS1, FLI1, FOCAD, FOSB, FOXJ2, FOXJ3, FRAT2, FUT4, GABARAP, GALM, GDAP2, GIMAP4, GLRX, GLRX3, GLYR1, GMFG, GNAQ, GNG5, GOLT1B, GPN3, GPR141, GPR27, GPS2, GPSM3, GRIPAP1, GRK3, GSN, GSR, GSTK1, GSTP1, H2AC6, H2AZ1, H2BC4, H3-3A, H4C8, HADHB, HLA-B, HLX, HMCES, HMGB1, HMGN2, HMGN4, HNRNPA1, HNRNPDL, HRH2, HSBP1, HSP90B2P, HSPB11, HSPD1, HTATIP2, IFI6, IFIT5, IFITM2, IGFLR1, IGSF6, IL17RA, INTS8, IRF1, ISCU, ITM2B, ITPR2, JPT1, KCTD12, KIAA1143, KIAA2013, KIDINS220, KIF2A, KPNA4, KPNB1, LAGE3, LAMTOR2, LAMTOR4, LAMTOR5, LARP7, LASP1, LEPROT, LEPROTL1, LIN7C, LINC00623, LINC00910, LINC01138, LINC01506, LINC02067, LINC02158, LIX1L, LLPH, LOC100506023, LOC100507507, LOC101928595, LOC102723373, LOC102723878, LOC105372421, LOC105372499, LOC105373098, LOC105373582, LOC105374102, LOC105374121, LOC105374985, LOC105375713, LOC105376244, LOC105376287, LOC105376512, LOC105376786, LOC105377067, LOC105378819, LOC107984747, LOC107986158, LOC107987225, LOC112268267, LOC643072, LPIN2, LSM3, LST1, LXN, LY96, LYPLA1, LYRM1, LYST, LYZ, MACROH2A1, MALSU1, MAN1A2, MAP2K4, MAPK1, MBD2, MCTS1, MED10, MED11, MED13L, MED25, METTL14, MICOS10, MIR142, MIR22HG, MMP25, MPC2, MRPL50, MRPL53, MRPS31, MRPS36, MS4A6A, MSRA, MTHFD2, MTMR1, MYLIP, NAA38, NACA4P, NAT9, NCF2, NDRG3, NDUFA1, NDUFA12, NDUFA2, NDUFA4, NDUFA5, NDUFA7, NDUFB1, NDUFB3, NDUFB6, NDUFV3, NEDD8, NEK7, NFRKB, NFYA, NLRC5, NMNAT1, NOP10, NOTCH1, NSD3, NSMCE1-DT, NTMT1, NUDT16, NUTF2, OARD1, OGFR, ORC4, ORMDL2, OSER1, OST4, OXR1, P2RY13, PABPC1, PAIP2, PARP14, PCMT1, PDCD4-AS1, PDPK1, PDPR, PELI2, PGLS, PGM2, PGM5, PHF21A, PHKB, PIGX, PIK3CD, PIN4, PLEKHA3, PLPBP, PNPT1, POLR2I, POLR2J, PPM1A, PPM1F, PPM1M, PPP2R5C, PQBP1, PRDX5, PRPF18, PRPF4B, PRR34-AS1, PRRG4, PSMA5, PSMA7, PSMB3, PSMB7, PSMB8, PSMD10, PSMD6, PSME1, PSME2, PSME4, PSTPIP1, PTBP2, PTENP1, PTOV1-AS2, PTPRN2, PXN, PYCARD, RAB33B, RAB5IF, RABAC1, RABGAP1, RABIF, RALBP1, RALY, RANBP3, RARA, RARS2, RASGRP2, RASSF3, RBM17, RBM26, RBP7, RCBTB2, RCOR1, RELCH, REM2, RFX1, RGS14, RHOT1, RNF114, RNF141, RNF145, RNF181, RNF20, RNF213, RNF38, RNF44, RNFT1, RNPEP, ROPN1L, RP2, RPA3, RPL13, RPL21, RPL23A, RPL24, RPL26, RPL27A, RPL29, RPL34, RPL35A, RPL36AL, RPL37, RPL38, RPL7A, RPL9, RPS11, RPS12, RPS15, RPS19, RPS19BP1, RPS24, RPS26, RPS27A, RPS3, RPS7, RPS9, RRP12, RSRP1, RTN4, RUFY2, S100A11, S100A12, S100A4, S100A6, S100A8, S100A9, S1PR4, SAP18, SAR1A, SBF2, SCAF8, SCARNA10, SCFD1, SCNM1, SDHB, SDHD, SEC11A, SEC22C, SEMA4A, SEMA4D, SENP5, SENP6, SERTAD3, SF3A1, SF3B5, SF3B6, SFPQ, SFSWAP, SGPL1, SH3GLB1, SIAH2, SLC25A5, SLC31A1, SLC35A1, SLC44A2, SLC45A4, SLC48A1, SLC8A1-AS1, SLCO3A1, SMARCA5, SMIM14, SMIM25, SMIM26, SMIM27, SMIM7, SNAPC5, SNF8, SNORA105A, SNORD141B, SNORD14D, SNORD14E, SNRK, SNRNP25, SNRNP27, SNRNP70, SNRPE, SNTB1, SNX2, SNX3, SP140, SP140L, SPCS1, SPIDR, SPTLC2, SREK1IP1, SRP14, SRSF9, SS18L2, ST3GAL6, STAG1, STAMBP, STAT2, STEAP4, STX3, STXBP5, SULT1B1, SUPT16H, SVBP, SWAP70, SYF2, TACC1, TAF10, TAF12, TARDBP, TBC1D1, TBCA, TBL1X, TFEB, TGFBR2, THAP1, THOC2, TIAL1, TIMM8B, TIPRL, TMA7, TMCO1, TMCO6, TMEM107, TMEM131L, TMEM144, TMEM14B, TMEM159, TMEM199, TMEM219, TMEM30A, TMEM50A, TMEM70, TMSB4X, TOPORS, TOR1AIP2, TPRG1L, TPST2, TRADD, TRAF3IP2-AS1, TRAPPC1, TRAPPC6B, TRDMT1, TRIOBP, TRMT10A, TRMT112, TSPAN2, TTC1, TTC17, TTC9C, TUBA1C, TUBGCP4, TUSC2, TXN, TXNDC17, TXNDC9, TXNIP, TXNL4B, TYROBP, U2AF1L5, UBA3, UBA52, UBC, UBE2D1, UBE2K, UBE2L3, UBE2R2, UBR3, UNC93B1, UPF2, UQCR10, UQCR11, UQCRC1, USP25, USP47, UTP6, VAMP3, VAMP4, VAMP5, VAPA, VNN2, VPS29, VPS36, VPS41, WBP4, WDR82, WDR83OS, WIPF1, WIPI1, XAF1, XPNPEP3, YIPF1, YPEL5, YY1, ZBTB18, ZBTB34, ZBTB8OS, ZCCHC9, ZDHHC17, ZFAS1, ZFP36L2, ZFP91, ZMAT2, ZMAT5, ZNF200, ZNF271P, ZNF284, ZNF516, ZNF641, ZNF700, ZNF770, ZNF776, ZNF90, ZNHIT1

\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find how to split the table as it doesn't seem possible, like David Carlisle said.

An alternative to keep this information still in a table but with the contents fitting into one page was to make the text tiny and have the table in landscape:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}


\begin{landscape} % Make the table landscape so less space is taken up with the first column
\tiny % Make table text tiny
\begin{longtable}{p{0.7in} >{\itshape}p{8in}}
    \caption{caption}
    \label{label}

    % Col names
    \hline
    \textbf{Group} & \textbf{Genes}
    \hline

    % contents of table:
Group 1 & ANKRD54, APC2, ARFGEF2, C3orf20, C6orf223, COQ9, DLEU1, DNLZ, DYRK3, ECI1, ERMARD, FAHD1, FBL, FBXO22, FBXO5, GATAD1, GPR143, GRAMD4, HCFC1, HEATR3, HSPA4L, HTR7P1, HYAL2, IRF5, KIF2C, LOC100996724, LOC102723324, LOC105376933, LOC105379437, LOC107984436, LOC107985246, LOC112268051, LOC729609, LPAR1, MAK16, MBNL1-AS1, MCM6, MFSD13B, MISP3, MPHOSPH10, MSANTD4, MYC, NHEJ1, NUP62, PIGM, PLA2G6, PNO1, PTTG2, RBM4B, SEMA7A, SLC52A2, SMAD7, SNORD36A, STT3A-AS1, TCERG1, THTPA, TIGD4, TIPIN, TMEM169, TNFAIP1, UGGT2, USP24, USP32P2, WDR77, ZDHHC4, ZNF142, ZNF320, ZNF584, ZNF815P\\

Group 2 & ABHD13, ABHD18, ABHD5, ABRACL, ABRAXAS1, ACBD3, ACSL4, ADD1, ADI1, AGO4, AHCTF1, AHCTF1P1, AIF1, AMFR, ANAPC13, ANKIB1, ANKRD42, ANP32B, ANXA11, ANXA3, AP3B1, AP3S1, APOL6, ARHGAP45, ARHGEF11, ARL3, ARL6IP4, ARPC4, ARPC5, ASH2L, ATAD1, ATF4, ATG4B, ATOX1, ATP5F1E, ATP5IF1, ATP5MC2, ATP5ME, ATP5MF, ATP5MG, ATP5MPL, ATP5PB, ATP7A, ATRX, BAG1, BBIP1, BICD2, BICRAL, BLOC1S2, BLZF1, BRCA1, BTBD10, BUD31, C11orf54, C19orf53, C2orf76, C4orf3, C4orf48, C5AR2, C6orf89, CAB39, CAB39L, CABP7, CALM1, CALM2, CALM3, CAMTA1, CARS2, CASC4, CASTOR2, CBFA2T3, CBFB, CBWD1, CBX1, CCDC13, CCDC146, CCDC170, CCDC71L, CCDC9, CD37, CD59, CDC40, CDK11A, CDKN2D, CEMIP2, CEP19, CEP57, CEP63, CFAP45, CFDP1, CHCHD7, CHD8, CHFR, CIAO1, CIAO2A, CINP, CIR1, CLEC12B, CLEC2B, CLMP, CLN8, CMTM2, CNBP, CNOT7, COMMD2, COMMD6, COP1, COPS5, COX14, COX17, COX5A, COX5B, COX6A1, COX6B1, COX8A, CPEB2, CPSF7, CREB5, CSNK1G3, CSTA, CTCF, CTDNEP1, CUL4B, CUX1, CXorf38, CYB561D2, CYB5B, CYB5R1, CYSLTR1, CYTOR, DAD1, DAPK1, DAPP1, DBI, DCAF7, DEF6, DEK, DENND10, DENND10P1, DIP2B, DNAJA2, DNAJB14, DNAJB6, DPH3, DPP8, DRC1, DTX3L, DUSP22, DYNLRB1, DYNLT1, EAF2, EEF1B2, EEPD1, EGLN1, EIF2S2, EIF4EBP1, EIF4EBP2, ELMOD2, ELOB, EMBP1, EMSY, ENY2, ERF, ESD, EVI2A, EVI2B, EXOSC3, FAM133B, FAM136A, FAM160B1, FAM200B, FAM204A, FAM49A, FAM76B, FAR1, FAS, FAU, FBXL3, FBXL4, FCGR1B, FIG4, FIS1, FLI1, FOCAD, FOSB, FOXJ2, FOXJ3, FRAT2, FUT4, GABARAP, GALM, GDAP2, GIMAP4, GLRX, GLRX3, GLYR1, GMFG, GNAQ, GNG5, GOLT1B, GPN3, GPR141, GPR27, GPS2, GPSM3, GRIPAP1, GRK3, GSN, GSR, GSTK1, GSTP1, H2AC6, H2AZ1, H2BC4, H3-3A, H4C8, HADHB, HLA-B, HLX, HMCES, HMGB1, HMGN2, HMGN4, HNRNPA1, HNRNPDL, HRH2, HSBP1, HSP90B2P, HSPB11, HSPD1, HTATIP2, IFI6, IFIT5, IFITM2, IGFLR1, IGSF6, IL17RA, INTS8, IRF1, ISCU, ITM2B, ITPR2, JPT1, KCTD12, KIAA1143, KIAA2013, KIDINS220, KIF2A, KPNA4, KPNB1, LAGE3, LAMTOR2, LAMTOR4, LAMTOR5, LARP7, LASP1, LEPROT, LEPROTL1, LIN7C, LINC00623, LINC00910, LINC01138, LINC01506, LINC02067, LINC02158, LIX1L, LLPH, LOC100506023, LOC100507507, LOC101928595, LOC102723373, LOC102723878, LOC105372421, LOC105372499, LOC105373098, LOC105373582, LOC105374102, LOC105374121, LOC105374985, LOC105375713, LOC105376244, LOC105376287, LOC105376512, LOC105376786, LOC105377067, LOC105378819, LOC107984747, LOC107986158, LOC107987225, LOC112268267, LOC643072, LPIN2, LSM3, LST1, LXN, LY96, LYPLA1, LYRM1, LYST, LYZ, MACROH2A1, MALSU1, MAN1A2, MAP2K4, MAPK1, MBD2, MCTS1, MED10, MED11, MED13L, MED25, METTL14, MICOS10, MIR142, MIR22HG, MMP25, MPC2, MRPL50, MRPL53, MRPS31, MRPS36, MS4A6A, MSRA, MTHFD2, MTMR1, MYLIP, NAA38, NACA4P, NAT9, NCF2, NDRG3, NDUFA1, NDUFA12, NDUFA2, NDUFA4, NDUFA5, NDUFA7, NDUFB1, NDUFB3, NDUFB6, NDUFV3, NEDD8, NEK7, NFRKB, NFYA, NLRC5, NMNAT1, NOP10, NOTCH1, NSD3, NSMCE1-DT, NTMT1, NUDT16, NUTF2, OARD1, OGFR, ORC4, ORMDL2, OSER1, OST4, OXR1, P2RY13, PABPC1, PAIP2, PARP14, PCMT1, PDCD4-AS1, PDPK1, PDPR, PELI2, PGLS, PGM2, PGM5, PHF21A, PHKB, PIGX, PIK3CD, PIN4, PLEKHA3, PLPBP, PNPT1, POLR2I, POLR2J, PPM1A, PPM1F, PPM1M, PPP2R5C, PQBP1, PRDX5, PRPF18, PRPF4B, PRR34-AS1, PRRG4, PSMA5, PSMA7, PSMB3, PSMB7, PSMB8, PSMD10, PSMD6, PSME1, PSME2, PSME4, PSTPIP1, PTBP2, PTENP1, PTOV1-AS2, PTPRN2, PXN, PYCARD, RAB33B, RAB5IF, RABAC1, RABGAP1, RABIF, RALBP1, RALY, RANBP3, RARA, RARS2, RASGRP2, RASSF3, RBM17, RBM26, RBP7, RCBTB2, RCOR1, RELCH, REM2, RFX1, RGS14, RHOT1, RNF114, RNF141, RNF145, RNF181, RNF20, RNF213, RNF38, RNF44, RNFT1, RNPEP, ROPN1L, RP2, RPA3, RPL13, RPL21, RPL23A, RPL24, RPL26, RPL27A, RPL29, RPL34, RPL35A, RPL36AL, RPL37, RPL38, RPL7A, RPL9, RPS11, RPS12, RPS15, RPS19, RPS19BP1, RPS24, RPS26, RPS27A, RPS3, RPS7, RPS9, RRP12, RSRP1, RTN4, RUFY2, S100A11, S100A12, S100A4, S100A6, S100A8, S100A9, S1PR4, SAP18, SAR1A, SBF2, SCAF8, SCARNA10, SCFD1, SCNM1, SDHB, SDHD, SEC11A, SEC22C, SEMA4A, SEMA4D, SENP5, SENP6, SERTAD3, SF3A1, SF3B5, SF3B6, SFPQ, SFSWAP, SGPL1, SH3GLB1, SIAH2, SLC25A5, SLC31A1, SLC35A1, SLC44A2, SLC45A4, SLC48A1, SLC8A1-AS1, SLCO3A1, SMARCA5, SMIM14, SMIM25, SMIM26, SMIM27, SMIM7, SNAPC5, SNF8, SNORA105A, SNORD141B, SNORD14D, SNORD14E, SNRK, SNRNP25, SNRNP27, SNRNP70, SNRPE, SNTB1, SNX2, SNX3, SP140, SP140L, SPCS1, SPIDR, SPTLC2, SREK1IP1, SRP14, SRSF9, SS18L2, ST3GAL6, STAG1, STAMBP, STAT2, STEAP4, STX3, STXBP5, SULT1B1, SUPT16H, SVBP, SWAP70, SYF2, TACC1, TAF10, TAF12, TARDBP, TBC1D1, TBCA, TBL1X, TFEB, TGFBR2, THAP1, THOC2, TIAL1, TIMM8B, TIPRL, TMA7, TMCO1, TMCO6, TMEM107, TMEM131L, TMEM144, TMEM14B, TMEM159, TMEM199, TMEM219, TMEM30A, TMEM50A, TMEM70, TMSB4X, TOPORS, TOR1AIP2, TPRG1L, TPST2, TRADD, TRAF3IP2-AS1, TRAPPC1, TRAPPC6B, TRDMT1, TRIOBP, TRMT10A, TRMT112, TSPAN2, TTC1, TTC17, TTC9C, TUBA1C, TUBGCP4, TUSC2, TXN, TXNDC17, TXNDC9, TXNIP, TXNL4B, TYROBP, U2AF1L5, UBA3, UBA52, UBC, UBE2D1, UBE2K, UBE2L3, UBE2R2, UBR3, UNC93B1, UPF2, UQCR10, UQCR11, UQCRC1, USP25, USP47, UTP6, VAMP3, VAMP4, VAMP5, VAPA, VNN2, VPS29, VPS36, VPS41, WBP4, WDR82, WDR83OS, WIPF1, WIPI1, XAF1, XPNPEP3, YIPF1, YPEL5, YY1, ZBTB18, ZBTB34, ZBTB8OS, ZCCHC9, ZDHHC17, ZFAS1, ZFP36L2, ZFP91, ZMAT2, ZMAT5, ZNF200, ZNF271P, ZNF284, ZNF516, ZNF641, ZNF700, ZNF770, ZNF776, ZNF90, ZNHIT1\\
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `! LaTeX Error: Environment landscape undefined.`

Comment: Who will read a table with so small fonts? BTW, you also need to load `array` package ...

Comment: and fix the error on `\hline`

Answer (score 0):

If you persist to use table even if for it you need to use `\tiny` font size and squish it on single page, than you may consider to use simple table in `sidewaystable` of `rotating` packages and for horizontal table lines use rules defined in the `booktabs package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}

\begin{document}


\begin{sidewaystable} 
    \caption{caption}
    \label{label}
\tiny % Make table text tiny
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}l >{\itshape}X @{}}
    \toprule
% column headers
\textbf{Group} & \textbf{Genes} \\
    \midrule
% contents of table:
Group 1 
& ANKRD54, APC2, ARFGEF2, C3orf20, C6orf223, COQ9, DLEU1, DNLZ, DYRK3, ECI1, ERMARD, FAHD1, FBL, FBXO22, FBXO5, GATAD1, GPR143, GRAMD4, HCFC1, HEATR3, HSPA4L, HTR7P1, HYAL2, IRF5, KIF2C, LOC100996724, LOC102723324, LOC105376933, LOC105379437, LOC107984436, LOC107985246, LOC112268051, LOC729609, LPAR1, MAK16, MBNL1-AS1, MCM6, MFSD13B, MISP3, MPHOSPH10, MSANTD4, MYC, NHEJ1, NUP62, PIGM, PLA2G6, PNO1, PTTG2, RBM4B, SEMA7A, SLC52A2, SMAD7, SNORD36A, STT3A-AS1, TCERG1, THTPA, TIGD4, TIPIN, TMEM169, TNFAIP1, UGGT2, USP24, USP32P2, WDR77, ZDHHC4, ZNF142, ZNF320, ZNF584, ZNF815P\\
    \addlinespace
Group 2 
& ABHD13, ABHD18, ABHD5, ABRACL, ABRAXAS1, ACBD3, ACSL4, ADD1, ADI1, AGO4, AHCTF1, AHCTF1P1, AIF1, AMFR, ANAPC13, ANKIB1, ANKRD42, ANP32B, ANXA11, ANXA3, AP3B1, AP3S1, APOL6, ARHGAP45, ARHGEF11, ARL3, ARL6IP4, ARPC4, ARPC5, ASH2L, ATAD1, ATF4, ATG4B, ATOX1, ATP5F1E, ATP5IF1, ATP5MC2, ATP5ME, ATP5MF, ATP5MG, ATP5MPL, ATP5PB, ATP7A, ATRX, BAG1, BBIP1, BICD2, BICRAL, BLOC1S2, BLZF1, BRCA1, BTBD10, BUD31, C11orf54, C19orf53, C2orf76, C4orf3, C4orf48, C5AR2, C6orf89, CAB39, CAB39L, CABP7, CALM1, CALM2, CALM3, CAMTA1, CARS2, CASC4, CASTOR2, CBFA2T3, CBFB, CBWD1, CBX1, CCDC13, CCDC146, CCDC170, CCDC71L, CCDC9, CD37, CD59, CDC40, CDK11A, CDKN2D, CEMIP2, CEP19, CEP57, CEP63, CFAP45, CFDP1, CHCHD7, CHD8, CHFR, CIAO1, CIAO2A, CINP, CIR1, CLEC12B, CLEC2B, CLMP, CLN8, CMTM2, CNBP, CNOT7, COMMD2, COMMD6, COP1, COPS5, COX14, COX17, COX5A, COX5B, COX6A1, COX6B1, COX8A, CPEB2, CPSF7, CREB5, CSNK1G3, CSTA, CTCF, CTDNEP1, CUL4B, CUX1, CXorf38, CYB561D2, CYB5B, CYB5R1, CYSLTR1, CYTOR, DAD1, DAPK1, DAPP1, DBI, DCAF7, DEF6, DEK, DENND10, DENND10P1, DIP2B, DNAJA2, DNAJB14, DNAJB6, DPH3, DPP8, DRC1, DTX3L, DUSP22, DYNLRB1, DYNLT1, EAF2, EEF1B2, EEPD1, EGLN1, EIF2S2, EIF4EBP1, EIF4EBP2, ELMOD2, ELOB, EMBP1, EMSY, ENY2, ERF, ESD, EVI2A, EVI2B, EXOSC3, FAM133B, FAM136A, FAM160B1, FAM200B, FAM204A, FAM49A, FAM76B, FAR1, FAS, FAU, FBXL3, FBXL4, FCGR1B, FIG4, FIS1, FLI1, FOCAD, FOSB, FOXJ2, FOXJ3, FRAT2, FUT4, GABARAP, GALM, GDAP2, GIMAP4, GLRX, GLRX3, GLYR1, GMFG, GNAQ, GNG5, GOLT1B, GPN3, GPR141, GPR27, GPS2, GPSM3, GRIPAP1, GRK3, GSN, GSR, GSTK1, GSTP1, H2AC6, H2AZ1, H2BC4, H3-3A, H4C8, HADHB, HLA-B, HLX, HMCES, HMGB1, HMGN2, HMGN4, HNRNPA1, HNRNPDL, HRH2, HSBP1, HSP90B2P, HSPB11, HSPD1, HTATIP2, IFI6, IFIT5, IFITM2, IGFLR1, IGSF6, IL17RA, INTS8, IRF1, ISCU, ITM2B, ITPR2, JPT1, KCTD12, KIAA1143, KIAA2013, KIDINS220, KIF2A, KPNA4, KPNB1, LAGE3, LAMTOR2, LAMTOR4, LAMTOR5, LARP7, LASP1, LEPROT, LEPROTL1, LIN7C, LINC00623, LINC00910, LINC01138, LINC01506, LINC02067, LINC02158, LIX1L, LLPH, LOC100506023, LOC100507507, LOC101928595, LOC102723373, LOC102723878, LOC105372421, LOC105372499, LOC105373098, LOC105373582, LOC105374102, LOC105374121, LOC105374985, LOC105375713, LOC105376244, LOC105376287, LOC105376512, LOC105376786, LOC105377067, LOC105378819, LOC107984747, LOC107986158, LOC107987225, LOC112268267, LOC643072, LPIN2, LSM3, LST1, LXN, LY96, LYPLA1, LYRM1, LYST, LYZ, MACROH2A1, MALSU1, MAN1A2, MAP2K4, MAPK1, MBD2, MCTS1, MED10, MED11, MED13L, MED25, METTL14, MICOS10, MIR142, MIR22HG, MMP25, MPC2, MRPL50, MRPL53, MRPS31, MRPS36, MS4A6A, MSRA, MTHFD2, MTMR1, MYLIP, NAA38, NACA4P, NAT9, NCF2, NDRG3, NDUFA1, NDUFA12, NDUFA2, NDUFA4, NDUFA5, NDUFA7, NDUFB1, NDUFB3, NDUFB6, NDUFV3, NEDD8, NEK7, NFRKB, NFYA, NLRC5, NMNAT1, NOP10, NOTCH1, NSD3, NSMCE1-DT, NTMT1, NUDT16, NUTF2, OARD1, OGFR, ORC4, ORMDL2, OSER1, OST4, OXR1, P2RY13, PABPC1, PAIP2, PARP14, PCMT1, PDCD4-AS1, PDPK1, PDPR, PELI2, PGLS, PGM2, PGM5, PHF21A, PHKB, PIGX, PIK3CD, PIN4, PLEKHA3, PLPBP, PNPT1, POLR2I, POLR2J, PPM1A, PPM1F, PPM1M, PPP2R5C, PQBP1, PRDX5, PRPF18, PRPF4B, PRR34-AS1, PRRG4, PSMA5, PSMA7, PSMB3, PSMB7, PSMB8, PSMD10, PSMD6, PSME1, PSME2, PSME4, PSTPIP1, PTBP2, PTENP1, PTOV1-AS2, PTPRN2, PXN, PYCARD, RAB33B, RAB5IF, RABAC1, RABGAP1, RABIF, RALBP1, RALY, RANBP3, RARA, RARS2, RASGRP2, RASSF3, RBM17, RBM26, RBP7, RCBTB2, RCOR1, RELCH, REM2, RFX1, RGS14, RHOT1, RNF114, RNF141, RNF145, RNF181, RNF20, RNF213, RNF38, RNF44, RNFT1, RNPEP, ROPN1L, RP2, RPA3, RPL13, RPL21, RPL23A, RPL24, RPL26, RPL27A, RPL29, RPL34, RPL35A, RPL36AL, RPL37, RPL38, RPL7A, RPL9, RPS11, RPS12, RPS15, RPS19, RPS19BP1, RPS24, RPS26, RPS27A, RPS3, RPS7, RPS9, RRP12, RSRP1, RTN4, RUFY2, S100A11, S100A12, S100A4, S100A6, S100A8, S100A9, S1PR4, SAP18, SAR1A, SBF2, SCAF8, SCARNA10, SCFD1, SCNM1, SDHB, SDHD, SEC11A, SEC22C, SEMA4A, SEMA4D, SENP5, SENP6, SERTAD3, SF3A1, SF3B5, SF3B6, SFPQ, SFSWAP, SGPL1, SH3GLB1, SIAH2, SLC25A5, SLC31A1, SLC35A1, SLC44A2, SLC45A4, SLC48A1, SLC8A1-AS1, SLCO3A1, SMARCA5, SMIM14, SMIM25, SMIM26, SMIM27, SMIM7, SNAPC5, SNF8, SNORA105A, SNORD141B, SNORD14D, SNORD14E, SNRK, SNRNP25, SNRNP27, SNRNP70, SNRPE, SNTB1, SNX2, SNX3, SP140, SP140L, SPCS1, SPIDR, SPTLC2, SREK1IP1, SRP14, SRSF9, SS18L2, ST3GAL6, STAG1, STAMBP, STAT2, STEAP4, STX3, STXBP5, SULT1B1, SUPT16H, SVBP, SWAP70, SYF2, TACC1, TAF10, TAF12, TARDBP, TBC1D1, TBCA, TBL1X, TFEB, TGFBR2, THAP1, THOC2, TIAL1, TIMM8B, TIPRL, TMA7, TMCO1, TMCO6, TMEM107, TMEM131L, TMEM144, TMEM14B, TMEM159, TMEM199, TMEM219, TMEM30A, TMEM50A, TMEM70, TMSB4X, TOPORS, TOR1AIP2, TPRG1L, TPST2, TRADD, TRAF3IP2-AS1, TRAPPC1, TRAPPC6B, TRDMT1, TRIOBP, TRMT10A, TRMT112, TSPAN2, TTC1, TTC17, TTC9C, TUBA1C, TUBGCP4, TUSC2, TXN, TXNDC17, TXNDC9, TXNIP, TXNL4B, TYROBP, U2AF1L5, UBA3, UBA52, UBC, UBE2D1, UBE2K, UBE2L3, UBE2R2, UBR3, UNC93B1, UPF2, UQCR10, UQCR11, UQCRC1, USP25, USP47, UTP6, VAMP3, VAMP4, VAMP5, VAPA, VNN2, VPS29, VPS36, VPS41, WBP4, WDR82, WDR83OS, WIPF1, WIPI1, XAF1, XPNPEP3, YIPF1, YPEL5, YY1, ZBTB18, ZBTB34, ZBTB8OS, ZCCHC9, ZDHHC17, ZFAS1, ZFP36L2, ZFP91, ZMAT2, ZMAT5, ZNF200, ZNF271P, ZNF284, ZNF516, ZNF641, ZNF700, ZNF770, ZNF776, ZNF90, ZNHIT1\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Anyway, I would rather stick with solution provided by @David Carlisle.